# Connecting to host mysql database using via sock

Tags: database, docker, docker-compose, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I am trying to connect to a mysql database on my host using a docker container (so I can use it in other containers).

*I would like to do it this way, because I cannot connect to the database from a docker container -> throws `Connection refused` because the IP is not allowed.*

I tried mounting the sock file using following compose:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mariadb:10.3
    volumes:
      - /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    networks:
      - database
networks:
  database:
    external: true
```

but it's failing on (even though the host database already contains many databases):

```
2022-06-07 20:14:46+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: Database is uninitialized and password option is not specified
You need to specify one of MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD, MARIADB_ALLOW_EMPTY_ROOT_PASSWORD and MARIADB_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD,
```

and when I added the volume: `- /var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql`, I am getting a `Connection refused` error (as if I was connecting to it normally and not via unix)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, consider checking the documentation before asking thoses types of questions
https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb

```
version: 3

services:
  sql:
    image: mariadb:10.3
    container_name: <container_name>
    restart: always
    networks:
      - database
    volumes:
      - <volume>:/var/lib/mysql
      - /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    environment:
      MARIADB_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1
      MARIADB_USER: <USER_TO_BE_CREATED>
      MARIADB_DATABASE: <DATABASE_TO_BE_CREATED>
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: <PASSWORD_TO_BE_CREATED>

networks:
  database:
    external: true
```